# Why doesn't `DefaultNancyBoostrapper` find my NancyModule

Tags: unit-testing, nancy

I'm just getting my feet wet in Nancy.  I was really excited to see the Testing process in the Wiki, but when I tried the following I couldn't get it work pass the tests at first.

Using VS2010

1. Created `Empty ASP.NET Web Application Project`: Notify.App
2. `Install-Package Nancy.Hosting.AspNet`
3. Created simple Module as listed below: NotifyModule
4. Created `Class Library` Project: Notify.UnitTests
5. `Install-Package Nancy.Testing`
6. `Install-Package XUnit`
7. Created simple first test: BaseUrlSpec.cs

Using `DefaultNancyBootstrapper` the test fails with `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`.

If I replace the `bootstrapper` definition with:

```cs
var bootstrapper = new ConfigurableBootstrapper(
                          with => 
                             with.Module<NotifyModule>());
```

**then the test passes.**  I don't understand why the SDHP using the DefaultNancyBootstrapper didn't work?  Did I do something wrong to make it break, or am I missing details in my understanding?

---

*NotifyModule*

```cs
using Nancy;
public class NotifyModule : NancyModule {
    public NotifyModule() {
        Get["/"] = _ => HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
}
```

*BaseUrlSpec*

```cs
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Testing;
using Notify.App;
using Xunit;
public class BaseUrlSpec
{
    [Fact]
    public void ShouldRespondOk()
    {
        var bootstrapper = new DefaultNancyBoostrapper();
        var app = new Browser(bootstrapper);
        var response = app.Get("/", with => with.HttpRequest());
        var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, statusCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make sure the assembly containing your route is loaded. Referencing a type from your assembly ensures this, therefore the version using the configurable bootstrapper works. 
To make the other one work, just add a reference to some type from your assembly. No need to instantiate it.

Comment: Christian is correct. This is a .NET thing, not a Nancy thing. If you were to do `var foo = typeof(NotifyModule)` in your test then it would pass with `DefaultNancyBootstrapper` However, in 0.17 we try to work around this, by loading all assemblies that references a Nancy assembly https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/1001

Comment: So, just having my app as one of the 'References' in the unit test library doesn't cause Nancy to pick it up.

Comment: No, an assembly reference is not enough. You need a reference in your code.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with Nancy. Under certain circumstances, the .net compiler will try to be smart and not include assemblies, with unused types, in the assembly manifest. If you were to inspect your test project assembly with this.GetType().Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies() you would not see your assembly with the module in it (unless you have the explicit use of the type). In 0.17 we try to work around this by loading everything in \bin with a reference to a Nancy* assembly.